# Problem with figures, captions and the main font in TexStudio

Tags: fonts, floats, symbols, captions, text

everybody! I have a problem with the "figure" environment. I have inserted several images one after the other

```
\ begin {figure}[htbp!]
\ caption {...}
\ centering \ includegraphics [...] {FIGURE1}
\ end {figure}

\ begin {figure}[htbp!]
\ caption {...}
\ centering \ includegraphics [...] {FIGURE2}
\ end {figure}
and so go on.
```

After inserting all the images and getting out from the "figure" environment, the font and size of the text remained the same as the caption and I cannot restore the main font. I tried to use several commands, such as \ pagestyle {}, \ mainmatter, but it was useless. I, also, tried to avoid the "figure" environment, but it figured out to be a bad decision. Is there anyone who can help me? I'm desperate

Comment: there is nothing in the code that you show that is related to fonts, and it is just a fragment sketch that no one can run to debug.  Please put a small but complete document into your question that shows the error. You can use `example-image` as the image as it is available for tests.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.